# How to pass parameter into SQL file from UNIX script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, unix, parameters, parameter-passing

I'm looking to pass in a parameter into a SQL file from my UNIX script. Unfortunately having problems with it.

Please see UNIX script below:

```
#!/bin/ksh
############

# Functions
_usage() {
SCRIPT_NAME=XXX
    -eq 1 -o "$1" = "" -o "$1" = help -o "$1" = Help -o "$1" = HELP ]; then
    echo "Usage: $SCRIPT_NAME [ cCode ]"
    echo " - For example : $SCRIPT_NAME GH\n"
    exit 1
fi
}

_initialise() {
cCode=$1
echo $cCode
}

# Set Variables
_usage $@
_initialise $1

# Main Processing
sql $DBNAME < test.sql $cCode > $PVNUM_LOGFILE
RETCODE=$?
# Check for errors within log file
if [[ $RETCODE != 0 ]] || grep 'E_' $PVNUM_LOGFILE
    then
    echo "Error - 50 - running test.sql. Please see $PVNUM_LOGFILE"
    exit 50
fi
```

Please see SQL script (test.sql):

```
SELECT DISTINCT v1.*
FROM data_latest v1
JOIN temp_table t
ON v1.number = t.id
WHERE v1.code = '&1'
```

The error I am receiving when running my UNIX script is:

```
INGRES TERMINAL MONITOR Copyright 2008 Ingres Corporation
E_US0022 Either the flag format or one of the flags is incorrect,
    or the parameters are not in proper order.
```

Anyone have any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: [Check This](https://communities.actian.com/s/article/COPYDB-fails-with-error-message-E-US0022)

Comment: @mathB The redirection symbol ("<") is being used in the sql line. As you can see below "sql $DBNAME < test.sql $cCode > $PVNUM_LOGFILE". Not sure if thats the issue?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the error, are you passing the parameter with correct format? Try this as well: In your SQL file `test.sql`, change `'&1'` to `'VaLuE'` and before you execute the sql, insert this command: `sed 's/VaLuE/$cCode/' /full/path/to/test.sql` and in your main process, remove `$cCode` and send the SQL file straight.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: While I don't work with the `sql` command, I do routinely pass UNIX parameters into SQL template/script files when using the `isql` command line tool, so fwiw ...

The first thing you'll want to do is replace the `&1` string with the value in the `cCode` variable; one typical method is to use `sed` to do a global search and replace of `&1` with `${cCode}` , eg:

```
$ cCode=XYZ
$ sed "s/\&1/${cCode}/g" test.sql

SELECT DISTINCT v1.*
FROM data_latest v1
JOIN temp_table t
ON v1.number = t.id
WHERE v1.code = 'XYZ'    <=== &1 replaced with XYZ
```

NOTE: You'll need to wrap the `sed` code in double quotes so that the value of the `cCode` variable can be referenced.

Now, to get this passed into `sql` there are a couple options ... capture the `sed` output to a new file and submit that file to `sql` or ... [and I'm guessing this is doable with `sql`], pipe the `sed` output into `sql`, eg:

```
sed "s/\&1/${cCode}/g" test.sql | sql $DBNAME > $PVNUM_LOGFILE
```

Answer (score 0):

You may need '\p\g' around your SQL in the text file?

I personally tend to code in the SQL to the script itself, as in

```
#!/bin/ksh

var=01.01.2018
db=database_name
OUTLOG=/path/log.txt

sql $db <<_END_ > $OUTLOG
    set autocommit on;
    \p\g
    set lockmode session where readlock = nolock;
    \p\g
    SELECT *
    FROM table
    WHERE date > '${var}' ; 
    \p\g
_END_

exit 0
```